# What's different: running in local tomcat vs. in cloud foundry

Tags: cassandra, cloud-foundry, hector

I have an application that runs just fine in a local tomcat instance - it's a cassandra client app that uses Hector as a client library for Cassandra.  The application creates a keyspace and column family (if it doesn't already exist) using code like the following:

```
final ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(keySpaceName,
    columnFamilyName, ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
    cfDef.setKeyValidationClass(ComparatorType.LONGTYPE.getClassName());
    cfDef.setComparatorType(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);

cfDef.addColumnDefinition(new BasicColumnDefinition() {{
    setName(StringSerializer.get().toByteBuffer("id"));
    setValidationClass(ComparatorType.LONGTYPE.getClassName());
}});
```

When I push this exact same application to cloud foundry (our own internal cloud where we have a simple cassandra service), the line above with "addColumnDefinition" results in an exception - here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.addColumnDefinition(ThriftCfDef.java:311)
org.pvtl.cassandra.HectorSample.createColumnFamily(HectorSample.java:94)
org.pvtl.cassandra.HectorSample.<init>(HectorSample.java:37)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:61)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

A bunch of googling and it looks like the trouble is that the Hector code is trying to add to an immutable list - the java.util.AbstractList.  But again, that code runs fine on my local tomcat instance so I'm thinking a difference in the jdk? Maybe? I'm running java 7 (sun) locally and pushed choosing java 7.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are using a different version of `Hector` in your local tomcat than the one in the server (i.e. server has older library) because the immutable list constrain was removed from newer `Hector` versions

[See this pull request discussion](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/pull/161)

**Edit**

You might want to check your server configuration and make sure it has the latest `hector` library and/or check that `hector-cor-xxx.jar` does **not** exist under your tomcat/jetty libraries folder as it might cause dependency problem.

Comment: Interesting thought and that constraint being removed from newer hector versions sure seems like a reasonable explanation.  But the hector-cor-1.1-2.jar is part of the war file that I am pushing. Some transitive dependency that is being satisfied by something on the dea differently than in my local tomcat or jetty? (works in local jetty as well).  Any idea how I can diagnose this?

Comment: If an older jar of `hector` library exists under your web server libraries folder it can cause such problem, see my updated answer

Comment: iTech - you are absolutely right.  There is an older version of the hector core jar in my /var/vcap/data/dea/apps/myapp/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ directory (as well as the newer jar).  So, now here's the $10K question - how did it get there?  It isn't in the war file that I pushed.

Comment: And then comes that embarrassing moment when you realize you were pushing a war file different from the one you were looking inside of...  The war file I was pushing did indeed have different versions on many of the jars.  Just pushed the right war file and everything is a-okay.  Thanks again!!

Comment: :) such things always happen